# Помогите с BeanPostProcessor, не отрабатывает

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Написал свой BeanPostProcessor для того, чтобы все методы, которые помечены моей аннотацией @Timing, выводил в консоль время их выполнения.

Использую SpringBoot.

Мой BeanPostProcessor выглядит следующим образом:

```
import com.example.version2.annotation.Timing;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

@Component
public class TimingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class type = bean.getClass();
        Method[] methods = type.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Timing.class)) {
                Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(type.getClassLoader(),type.getInterfaces(), new InvocationHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                        long before = System.nanoTime();
                        Object retVal = method.invoke(bean, args);
                        long after = System.nanoTime();
                        System.out.println("Method worked: " + (after - before) + " nano seconds");
                        return retVal;
                    }
                });
                return proxy;
            } else {
                return bean;
            }
        }

         return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

}
```

И собственно моя аннотация:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Timing {
}
```

Вешаю аннотацию над одним из методов в dao классе:

```
@Timing
public  List<Map<String, Object>> selectQuery() {
    String selectQuery = prop.getMYSQL_SELECT();
    return mysqlTemplate.queryForList(selectQuery);
}
```

При старте приложения проблем нет, выполняю запрос, но в консоли ничего не вижу.
Вроде бы сам BeanPostProcessor написал верно. Не могу найти в чем ошибка. 
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Также хотелось бы узнать, как мне эту информацию о времени выполнении метода передать на фронтенд в json или каком-нибудь List (не принципиально).

Буду очень благодарен за подсказку.
Спасибо.

Comment: Это что-то в исследовательских целях? Иначе почему бы не взять https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html

Comment: @RuslanP. спасибо, посмотрел метрики, оказалось действительно очень полезная штука.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создавайте один прокси для всех методов, иначе на первом же методе без аннотации постпроцессор вернет не проксированный бин:
1. смотрите, наличие аннотации хоть у одного метода
2. создаете прокси на бин
3. внутри invoke проверяете у метода наличие аннотации

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!